# How can i combine two outputs of two independent rnn with keras and train the new model?

Tags: networking, keras, deep-learning, output, convolution

I have two independent cnn network for image classification with keras. the idea is to combine the outputs of this two networks (output"A" and output"B") and to train the new model in the way that optimise the final result using a softmax classifior.
i did already train every networks alone.
Any solution please?

Comment: Please edit your question and include more details: did you train two networks on the same dataset? What is their architectures, i.e. what layers they have, how the layers are connected to each other? And if possible, include their codes in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Very broad question, if you want more specific answers you'll have to supply something you've tried and an explanation of what's not working.

That being said you can most often achieve better results just by averaging predictions from two different models (assuming both models are actually somewhat good). If you want to learn more advanced methods and learn about stacking / model ensemble in general I suggest reading http://blog.kaggle.com/2016/12/27/a-kagglers-guide-to-model-stacking-in-practice/

Comment: You're right that the models itself is not deep learning but that's because it's probably not the best approach for this type of data. It's too few variables, in this case only two. XGBoost is also very popular for this purpose, see https://www.kaggle.com/arthurtok/introduction-to-ensembling-stacking-in-python for an example. However once you have your data setup in that format it's very easy to use Keras to fit it using any model you wish.